# Can't load data from JSON in TVML app with ATVJS

Tags: javascript, tvml

I am working on a TVML app using the ATVJS plugin. I have succeeded in creating a static page built with hardcoded template and data. However, if I try to use dynamic data together with Mustache, the template doesn't work and I get a blank screen.

This is the code I'm using:

```
ATV.Page.create({
    name: 'main',
    template(data, url) {

       var tmplt = `<document>
       <mainTemplate>
          <background>
             <img src="${data.image}" />
          </background>
          <menuBar>
             <section>
                <menuItem>
                   <title> {{ catalog }}</title>
                </menuItem>
                <menuItem>
                   <title>Option 2</title>
                </menuItem>
             </section>
          </menuBar>
       </mainTemplate>
       </document>`;
       return Mustache.render(tmplt, url);
       },

    data: {
        image: baseurl + 'images/main.jpg'
    },

    url : 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/data.json'

});
```

The JSON file I'm using is very simple since this is just a test:

```
{
  "catalog" : "Option 1"
}
```

If I hardcode the menu item's title, everything works

```
<title>Option 1</title>
```

but as soon as I try to get the data, I get a blank screen

```
<title>{{ catalog }}</title>
```

Answer (score -1):

Late post, but might be worth it.

I can see two issues with the above structure.

1. Using raw `data` object, as well as `url` config to fetch remote json
2. Not passing the correct object to the `Mustache.render` function

Solution:

1. Use if you want to use dynamic object, along with remote url fetch, pass `data` function. See example https://github.com/emadalam/atvjs#fetching-data-from-a-remote-source
2. Pass your data as the second param to the `Mustache.render` function. See usage example https://github.com/janl/mustache.js#usage.

Something like below should work fine.

```es6
var image = `${baseurl}images/main.jpg`;
ATV.Page.create({
  name: 'main',
  url : 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/data.json',
  template(data) {
    var tmplt = `<document>
      <mainTemplate>
        <background>
          <img src="${image}" />
        </background>
        <menuBar>
          <section>
            <menuItem>
              <title> {{ catalog }}</title>
            </menuItem>
            <menuItem>
              <title>Option 2</title>
            </menuItem>
          </section>
        </menuBar>
      </mainTemplate>
    </document>`;
    return Mustache.render(tmplt, data);
  }
});
```